# Click on button in another program - FindWindow, C#

Tags: c#, findwindow

I'm trying to create a program that will be able to control another program (in Windows).

I found this code:

```
// Get a handle to an application window.
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
                                       string lpWindowName);

// Activate an application window.
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

//button event
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get a handle to the Calculator application. The window class 
    // and window name were obtained using the Spy++ tool.
    IntPtr calculatorHandle = FindWindow("CalcFrame", "Kalkulačka");

    // Verify that Calculator is a running process. 
    if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Calculator is not running.");
        return;
    }

    // Make Calculator the foreground application and send it  
    // a set of calculations.
    SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);
    SendKeys.SendWait("111");
    SendKeys.SendWait("*");
    SendKeys.SendWait("11");
    SendKeys.SendWait("=");
}
```

Is is possible to simulate CLICK on button? How? It is possible to click on program in the background?

Can you show me an example ?

Comment: yes this is possible I believe this may lend you some ideas -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502035/perform-a-mouse-click-event-on-another-application-using-c-sharp if not then perform a simple google search

Comment: possible duplicate of [Control another application using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134993/control-another-application-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes, i read this, but i dont know how to use library. I think is there a another way.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the answer in other posts:

[programmatically mouse click in another window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355286/programmatically-mouse-click-in-another-window)

or

[Send mouse clicks to X Y coordinate of another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747004/send-mouse-clicks-to-x-y-coordinate-of-another-application)

I hope they help.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, but i thing this selution it is NOT in bacground task ?... ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to simulate mouse click:

```
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

        public const int MOUSE_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
        public const int MOUSE_LEFTUP = 0x04;

        public static void LeftMouseClick(int x, int y)
        {
            SetCursorPos(x, y);
            mouse_event(MOUSE_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSE_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
        }
```

Method `LeftMouseClick` is getting two parameters x and y representing coordinates on user screen:

```
LeftMouseClick(400, 200);
```

Or you can do it by keyboard:
[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
       SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }
```

basically that's what you are doing in your code:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("111");
SendKeys.SendWait("*");
SendKeys.SendWait("11");
SendKeys.SendWait("=");
```

I dont think there is another way of doing this.

Comment: @phawres You can send keystrokes to the active application, that is the closest you can get to "looking" as a backround operation, see edit above.

Comment: @phawres you can only do it in background by accessing some sort of powershell, application-programming interface (API), macro or dll. If an aplication dosnt support that type of access you can not do it programmatically or as a backround operation.