# UI automation with another application

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I need to interact with a windows application by clicking a button in my application. More precisely: how can I write in a textbox or scroll a dropdown menu?

Comment: You will need to use the underlying Win32 API using pinvoke.
FindWindow or similar to get the main window handle.



This covers most of it.. the concept is the same.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589908/click-on-button-in-another-program-findwindow-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this depending on what kind of application you are automating. If you are automating a WPF application I would suggesting using Microsoft UI Automation (UIA). There are some nice wrappers written around UIA like [TestStack.White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) and [FlaUI](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI). [FlaUI](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI) is the more modern of the two and supports [UIAv3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) using a COM wrapper. [TestStack.White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) is built on top of a [UIAv2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation?view=netframework-4.7.2) using the managed wrapper in the .NET Framework which is no longer supported.

If you are automating anything else besides a WPF application you can do straight PInvokes to [SendMessage](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage). I would suggest staying away from that method and using the Microsoft UIA framework since sending windows messages can get quite verbose. If you really want to go with the Win32 route I suggest using something like [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) to automate your application.

Lastly, you will want to download the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and run [Inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/inspect-objects) from that. [Inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/inspect-objects) is the application that will allow you to see the properties you are attempting to query and the patterns that are available. Applications like [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) have essentially built their own [Inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/inspect-objects) or reference and application call UISpy which is also in the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) but mostly superseded by [Inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/inspect-objects).